# Very slow Wi-fi connection and makes the Wi-fi slow on other devices as well

Tags: wireless

I just started using Ubuntu and when i try to install Wine or other programs the wifi is not only very slow not only on ubuntu but on every device connected to that same wifi, I have a Lenovo laptop with integrated Realtek network card

Comment: you sure this isn't an issue with your router? Because it sounds like a router problem or hardware problem on your wifi network side not your computer's side.

Comment: I did think of that at first but the router's fine, as soon as i disconnect from wifi on Ubuntu laptop it starts working properly, pretty fast connection too, then i connect again and literally start using firefox it goes to crap in about a minute